# Can DMS be configured to run in INSERT only mode?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We have a large MySQL table of sales that we would like to replicate over to Redshift, streaming data using AWS Database Migration Service (DMS). This table is insert only. Once a sale is added it is never deleted or modified.

We would like to prune sales after a TTL regularly (they would then be in Redshift) to keep the table small. However deleting records would be replicated over to Redshift.

It is possible for DMS to either discard DELETEs or otherwise prevent the records from being deleted from the Redshift target?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot do this from the AWS DMS. However, you should be looking at the MYSQL replication properties to see if there a way you can tell mysql not to replicate deletes from the Binary Logs?

I know this can be done when source is SQL Server where we can tell sql server replication to not propagate deletes (as attached).

[Screenshot from SQL Server Replication Properties for DMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jptV.png)